# Does the ternary operator short circuit in a defined way

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, conditional-operator, short-circuiting

If you have the following:

```
if (x)
{
    y = *x;
}
else
{
    y = 0;
}
```

Then behavior is guaranteed to be defined since we can only dereference `x` if it is not 0

Can the same be said for:

```
y = (x) ? *x : 0;
```

This seems to work as expected (even compiled with `-Wpedantic` on g++)

Is this guaranteed?

Comment: Yes - The ternary operator is just syntactic sugar

Comment: Yes.  (Too short to be posted as an answer).

Comment: There's no "short circuit" in the ternary expression. And it doesn't prematurely evaluate or execute any branch either before the condition have been fully evaluated.

Comment: @EdHeal I can't think of what it would be syntactic sugar for.

Comment: For the `if` statemet

Comment: @EdHeal But the conditional operator gives you an expression, not a statement.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, only the second or third operand will be evaluated, the draft C++ standard section `5.16` *[expr.cond]* says:

> Conditional expressions group right-to-left. The first expression is contextually converted to bool (Clause 4).
>   It is evaluated and if it is true, the result of the conditional expression is the value of the second expression,
>   otherwise that of the third expression. **Only one of the second and third expressions is evaluated.** Every value
>   computation and side effect associated with the first expression is sequenced before every value computation
>   and side effect associated with the second or third expression.

Comment: So, `x ? *x++ : 0` will not increment `x` iff `x == 0`